# Can I get a Visual Studio 2015 Command Prompt when I only have VS2019 installed?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2019

I have a copy of Visual Studio 2019 Professional installed, and I have installed the MSVC v140 build tools to allow me to build my code against the Visual C++ 2015 runtime.

I know that I can load environment variables for MSVC v142 like this...

```
$ "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vsvarsall.bat" x64
```

... to enable me to build from the command line. Is there any way of doing the same thing for v140, without having visual studio 2015 installed, or do I have to write my own batch script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try this option to set up the environment for the v140?

```
$ "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vsvarsall.bat" x86_x64 -vcvars_ver=14.0
```

In folder C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\Build there are four developer command prompts (named vcvars*.bat). Pick any one and create a copy to edit.

These all files just invoke vcvarsall.bat with the proper architecture parameter. We’ll do the same, but add a new parameter that tells vcvarsall.bat to set up the environment for the v140 toolset:  -vcvars_ver=14.0.

for more detail check out [this blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/visual-studio-build-tools-now-include-the-vs2017-and-vs2015-msvc-toolsets/)

Comment: Perfect! Thank you for your help.